# How to get the first and last element of a range vector in promql

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to get the first and last element in a range vector retunred by a query that is similar to this:

`container_memory_usage_bytes[1h]`

In the resultset I get a list of timestamps and memory values for each pod in the hour.

```
3863654400 @1629726924.874
3863539712 @1629726955.72
3863900160 @1629726984.032
3863937024 @1629727016.102
3863515136 @1629727049.814
3863703552 @1629727077.533
3863506944 @1629727104.48
3863896064 @1629727128.676
```

If I only want to know what the first index and the last index of this array is i-e, the first record in the hour and the last record in the hour for each pod, how would I structure the query ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `last_over_time` function as it is described [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

> last_over_time(range-vector): the most recent point value in specified interval.

```
last_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes[1h])
```

I didn't find `first_over_time` for Prometheus. Maybe there is another way to do it in Prometheus. Although, Grafana has the `first_over_time` as [it is shown here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/#metric-queries). And as @valyala said, if you install and configure [VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#prometheus-setup) you can use it [as described here](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#first_over_time).

Comment: The `first_over_time` function exists in MetricsQL from VictoriaMetrics - [see these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#first_over_time).

Comment: that is true, I also saw that. but how would I use `VictoriaMetrics` in a prometheus dashboard? Only if it is installed https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Single-server-VictoriaMetrics.html#prometheus-setup

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@ start()` and `@ end()` like specified [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier).

```
http_requests_total @ start()
http_requests_total @ end()
```